# Better way to loop Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

My code works fine and returns what I need, however I am wondering if there is a cleaner, or more importantly more performant way of doing it.

I am calling an API to return me a list of IDs, then in the code below, I use the following to loop through each ID returned. I then Promise.all, and then flatten the results into on array.

```
// Previous API call
console.log(invoices.data) // [1,2,3,4]

// Loop through the array above and collect all details for each ID    
const invoiceDetails = await invoices.data.map(async id => {
  const res = await axios.get(
     `${baseURL}` +
       `invoice/${id}`
  );
  return res.data;
});

// Promise.all results
const invoiceDetailsResponse = await Promise.all(invoiceDetails);

// Once all have returned, flatted into one array
const flattenedinvoiceDetails = [].concat(...invoiceDetailsResponse);
```

So, if the above is clear, just wondering if anyone has a better suggestion on how they would do this?

Comment: This is a nice way to do it, i do this for my use-cases all the time. Just one heads-up always wrap you async actions in try/catch. The rest looks solid.

Comment: Great, thank you! Yes, I actually do have a try/catch I just copied the code within.

Comment: Depending on how many requests you are queuing up the memory stack can hurt if you are queuing up a dynamic list. However running them in parallel like you do in your example can have some performance boost compared to running them one by one. I also tend to do your approach depending on the use case.